# Failed auto update retrieval of third-party root list

Tags: windows-server-2003

I am getting a lot of these message in the event log of a Windows 2003 Std. Server.

---

Source: crypt32

Event ID: 8

Description:
Failed auto update retrieval of third-party root list sequence number from:
http://www.download.windowsupdate.com/msdownload/update/v3/static/trustedr/en/authrootseq.txt with error:
The specified server cannot perform the requested operat

---

The Servers function is to run Cisco Works LMS 3.1. Nothing else is installed. The server has no connection to the internet, could that be the reason for those error messages and if so, how could I updates those thirdparty lists manually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

KB 317541 (Event ID 8 is logged in the Application log): http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317541 has the answer.

**Cause:** This behavior can occur if the Update Root Certificates component is turned on and the computer cannot connect to the Windows Update server on the Internet. The Update Root Certificates component automatically updates trusted root-certificate authorities from the Microsoft Update server at regular intervals.

**Resolution:** To resolve this behavior, you must connect to the Internet or turn off the Update Root Certificates component. To turn off the Update Root Certificates component, follow these steps:

1. In Control Panel, double-click Add/Remove Programs.
2. Click Add/Remove Windows Components.
3. Click to clear the Update Root Certificates check box, and then continue with the Windows Components Wizard.

Comment: Any idea on whether I can do this to multiple machines at once via GPO or some other automated method?